# Debugging with Xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging

I know that Xcode is supposed to make debugging "easier". Could someone how this works (At the moment NSLog() is my only debugging tool :D)

Thanks

Comment: What, specifically, are you looking for? Instructions on how to use a debugger? How to set breakpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to turn the breakpoints on (in toolbar) and then press Run.

[image]

Afterwards you set View/Show Debug Area (CMD+SHIFT+Y) to show the debug view. Set a breakpoint at the line you are interested in by clicking at the line number in the left panel. Now execution stops and you can inspect the variables. Use the Product / Debug menu for execute the code step by step to see what's going on.

It's pretty handy and you won't miss it once you get used to it. Be careful with NSLog statements especially when developing for iPhone, they are very expensive in terms of preformance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add breakpoints and view values currently stored in variables when you hit any breakpoint.  What more are you looking for in a debugger?

Comment: I've played with breakpoints but could never find any useful information, for example the value of a string. It seems to just spit out tons of memory adresses (As it's probably supposed to).

Comment: Have you tried using nslog() like this?   NSLog(@"My String: %@",myNSStr); That gives you the value in the myNSStr down in the debug window.

Comment: That what I was attempting to get away from, my programs become littered with statements like those.

Comment: In the debugger, if you want to print a string, use `po myString`. (`po` is a shortcut for `print-object`)